# How to insert a slider in Pygame?

Tags: python, slider, pygame

I am currenctly working on a physics simulation on Python, simulating a gas cloud in a chamber using Pygame . 
My problem is that I can't insert a working slider in my code to change the value of a parameter.
I have a "while running" loop that runs the simulation, and when I want to insert a working slider in it, the simulation stops. I can't have both simulation and slider working.

Below is the code for the slider:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# set window size
width = 640
height = 100

# initilaise pygame
pygame.init()
windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),1,16)
redColor = pygame.Color(255,0,0)
blackColor = pygame.Color(0,0,0)

#starting position
x = 100
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurfaceObj,redColor,Rect(x,5,10,90))
pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(0,0,width,height))

s = 0
while s == 0:
    button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if button[0] != 0:
       pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
       x = pos[0]
       y = pos[1]
       a = x - 5
       if a < 0:
          a = 0
       pygame.draw.rect(windowSurfaceObj,blackColor,Rect(0,0,width,height))
       #pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(0,0,width,height))
       pygame.draw.rect(windowSurfaceObj,redColor,Rect(a,5,10,90))
       pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(0,0,width,height))


   # check for ESC key pressed, or pygame window closed, to quit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()
       elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The slider code seems fine to me, and it works on my computer.  Is the simulation code in a separate while loop?  If so, you have to combine the two loops into one because the slider loop is never going to break.

For example, if the slider was controlling the growth rate, you could write it like this and draw the gas cloud onto `windowSurfaceObj`.  For this to work well, you would make `windowSurfaceObj` bigger and set up two separate surfaces for the slider and gas cloud.  In that case, you would draw onto the separate surfaces and blit the separate surfaces to `windowSurfaceObj`.  You would also have to do collision detection to determine if the mouse is clicking inside the slider.

```
# imports and Pygame initialization here

a = 0
size_of_gas_cloud = 30

while True:

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] != 0:
        # collision detection also needed here
        a = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - 5
        if a < 0:
            a = 0

    size_of_gas_cloud += a

    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurfaceObj, blackColor, Rect(0, 0, width, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurfaceObj, redColor, Rect(a, 5, 10, 90))
    pygame.display.update()

    # Pygame event loop here
```

Comment: The problem is that if I combine the slider loop in my main loop, the simulation does not start : only the slider loop is active and never ends . 
How can I integrate the slider loop to my simulation without being stuck  in the slider loop ? 

Thanks for the answer

Comment: For this to work with Pygame, you should have only one loop where all your simulation logic, mouse event handling and screen drawing happen.  See the example.  Also, everything has to happen in one window.  Are you trying to make a pop-up window with a slider in it?  I don't think that will work with Pygame.  You can make this work by writing your own widgets, but the library mentioned in Malik Brahimi's answer is also worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

I improved on the original code in my way. Here it is. It is built so you just use two lines to define the slider in your loop (one to initialise it (sliderInit()) and one to execute it (slier())).

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
# screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screenColor = (255,255,255)
screen.fill(screenColor)
pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(0,0,1920,1080))

def slider(sx,sy,action,width,height,buttonColor,sliderColor,buttonBorderThickness,sliderBorderThickness,buttonWidth,sliderBarHeight,maxValue):
    if mouse[0] > sx and mouse[0] < sx+width and mouse[1] > sy and mouse[1] < sy+height:
        if click[0] == 1:
            mouseX = mouse[0] - 5
            if mouseX < sx:
                mouseX = sx
            elif mouseX > sx+width-buttonWidth:
                mouseX = sx+width-buttonWidth
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,screenColor,(sx,sy,width,height))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,sliderColor,(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,buttonColor,(mouseX,sy,buttonWidth,height))
            if buttonBorderThickness != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(mouseX,sy,buttonWidth,height),buttonBorderThickness)
            if sliderBorderThickness != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight),sliderBorderThickness)
            pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(sx,sy,width,height))
            
            if action == "test1":
                sliderValue = (mouseX-sx)/((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue)
                print("test1:")
                print(sliderValue)
            elif action == "test2":
                sliderValue = (mouseX-sx)/((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue)
                print("test2:")
                print(sliderValue)

def sliderInit(sx,sy,width,height,buttonColor,sliderColor,buttonBorderThickness,sliderBorderThickness,buttonWidth,sliderBarHeight,maxValue,startValue):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,screenColor,(sx,sy,width,height))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,sliderColor,(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,buttonColor,(sx+startValue*((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue),sy,buttonWidth,height))
        if buttonBorderThickness != 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(sx+startValue*((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue),sy,buttonWidth,height),buttonBorderThickness)
        if sliderBorderThickness != 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight),sliderBorderThickness)
        pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(sx,sy,width,height))

firstLoop = True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    
    if firstLoop == True:
        sliderInit(100,50,1000,50,(255,255,255),(220,220,220),1,0,25,10,100,50)
        sliderInit(100,120,1000,50,(255,255,255),(220,220,220),1,0,25,10,100,50)
        firstLoop = False
    
    slider(100,50,"test1",1000,50,(255,255,255),(220,220,220),1,0,25,10,100)
    slider(100,120,"test2",1000,50,(255,255,255),(220,220,220),1,0,25,10,100)
```

Here is also the code to create a slider with 10 steps.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
# screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screenColor = (255,255,255)
screen.fill(screenColor)
pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(0,0,1920,1080))

def slider(sx,sy,width,height,action,
               buttonColor,buttonBorderThickness,buttonWidth,
               sliderBarColor,sliderBarBorderThickness,sliderBarHeight,
               sliderStepColor,sliderStepBorderThickness,sliderStepWidth,sliderStepHeight,sliderStepSnap,
               maxValue):
    
    if mouse[0] > sx and mouse[0] < sx+width and mouse[1] > sy and mouse[1] < sy+height:
        if click[0] == 1:
            mouseX = mouse[0] - 5
            if mouseX < sx+sliderStepSnap:
                mouseX = sx
            
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+10*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+10*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+10*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+20*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+20*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+20*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2) 
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+30*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+30*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+30*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+40*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+40*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+40*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+50*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+50*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+50*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+60*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+60*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+60*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+70*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+70*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+70*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+80*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+80*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+80*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            elif mouseX > (round(sx+90*((width)/100))-sliderStepSnap) and mouseX < (round(sx+90*((width)/100))+sliderStepSnap):
                mouseX = round(sx+90*((width)/100)-buttonWidth/2)
            
            elif mouseX > sx+width-buttonWidth-sliderStepSnap:
                mouseX = sx+width-buttonWidth
            
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,screenColor,(sx,sy,width,height))
            
            for i in range(1,10):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,sliderStepColor,(round(sx+i*10*((width)/100)),sy+(height-sliderStepHeight)/2,sliderStepWidth,sliderStepHeight))
                if sliderStepBorderThickness != 0:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(round(sx+i*10*((width)/100)),sy+(height-sliderStepHeight)/2,sliderStepWidth,sliderStepHeight),sliderStepBorderThickness)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,sliderBarColor,(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight))
            
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,buttonColor,(mouseX,sy,buttonWidth,height))
            if buttonBorderThickness != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(mouseX,sy,buttonWidth,height),buttonBorderThickness)
            if sliderBarBorderThickness != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight),sliderBarBorderThickness)
            pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(sx,sy,width,height))
            
            if action == "test1":
                sliderValue = (mouseX-sx)/((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue)
                print("test1:")
                print(sliderValue)
            elif action == "test2":
                sliderValue = (mouseX-sx)/((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue)
                print("test2:")
                print(sliderValue)

def sliderInit(sx,sy,width,height,
               buttonColor,buttonBorderThickness,buttonWidth,
               sliderBarColor,sliderBarBorderThickness,sliderBarHeight,
               sliderStepColor,sliderStepBorderThickness,sliderStepWidth,sliderStepHeight,
               maxValue,startValue):
        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,screenColor,(sx,sy,width,height))
        
        for i in range(1,10):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,sliderStepColor,(round(sx+i*10*((width)/100)),sy+(height-sliderStepHeight)/2,sliderStepWidth,sliderStepHeight))
            if sliderStepBorderThickness != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(round(sx+i*10*((width)/100)),sy+(height-sliderStepHeight)/2,sliderStepWidth,sliderStepHeight),sliderStepBorderThickness)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,sliderBarColor,(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight))
    
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,buttonColor,(sx+startValue*((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue),sy,buttonWidth,height))
        if buttonBorderThickness != 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(sx+startValue*((width-buttonWidth)/maxValue),sy,buttonWidth,height),buttonBorderThickness)
        if sliderBarBorderThickness != 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(sx,sy+height/2-sliderBarHeight/2,width,sliderBarHeight),sliderBorderThickness)
        pygame.display.update(pygame.Rect(sx,sy,width,height))

firstLoop = True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                turnOffMotors()
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    
    if firstLoop == True:
        sliderInit(100,50,1000,50,
               (255,255,255),1,25,
               (220,220,220),0,10,
               (0,0,0),0,5,40,
               100,50)
        sliderInit(100,120,1000,50,
               (255,255,255),1,25,
               (220,220,220),0,10,
               (0,0,0),0,5,40,
               100,50)
        firstLoop = False
    
    slider(100,50,1000,50,"test1",
           (255,255,255),1,25,
           (220,220,220),0,10,
           (0,0,0),0,5,40,30,
           100)
    slider(100,120,1000,50,"test2",
           (255,255,255),1,25,
           (220,220,220),0,10,
           (0,0,0),0,5,40,30,
           100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can complicatedly create your own slider with a rectangle and a circle that respond to mouse events, but I suggest you take a look into Kivy sliders instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did a slider that i used as volume controller to the background music

I did a slider that i used as volume controller to the background music

```
class Slider:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.circle_x = x
        self.volume = 0
        self.sliderRect = pg.Rect(x, y, w, h)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.sliderRect)
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (255, 240, 255), (self.circle_x, (self.sliderRect.h / 2 + self.sliderRect.y)), self.sliderRect.h * 1.5)

    def get_volume(self):
        return self.volume

    def set_volume(self, num):
        self.volume = num

    def update_volume(self, x):
        if x < self.sliderRect.x:
            self.volume = 0
        elif x > self.sliderRect.x + self.sliderRect.w:
            self.volume = 100
        else:
            self.volume = int((x - self.sliderRect.x) / float(self.sliderRect.w) * 100)

    def on_slider(self, x, y):
        if self.on_slider_hold(x, y) or self.sliderRect.x <= x <= self.sliderRect.x + self.sliderRect.w and self.sliderRect.y <= y <= self.sliderRect.y + self.sliderRect.h:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def on_slider_hold(self, x, y):
        if ((x - self.circle_x) * (x - self.circle_x) + (y - (self.sliderRect.y + self.sliderRect.h / 2)) * (y - (self.sliderRect.y + self.sliderRect.h / 2)))\
               <= (self.sliderRect.h * 1.5) * (self.sliderRect.h * 1.5):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def handle_event(self, screen, x):
        if x < self.sliderRect.x:
            self.circle_x = self.sliderRect.x
        elif x > self.sliderRect.x + self.sliderRect.w:
            self.circle_x = self.sliderRect.x + self.sliderRect.w
        else:
            self.circle_x = x
        self.draw(screen)
        self.update_volume(x)
        print(self.volume)
```